# How can I use the value of a stringgrid cell to be stored in an array which should hold the current game state?

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm new to programming and am trying to make a delphi tictactoe game using a 3x3 array, as a way to help me learn the basics.

I'm using a stringgrid which I wanted to show the state of the board, the user places an X on the cell (via mouse click). I was hoping at this part in the code it would add the 'X' to the gameboard array using the stringgrid.cell(ARow,ACol) for the position. I've now learnt that this cannot work as the array is a char type. Is there a way around this?

I know this is not the best way to make a game, but it's helping me learn. Any help would be very appreciated. Here's my code:

````
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ButtonGroup,
  Vcl.Grids;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    label1: TLabel;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    Button2: TButton;

    procedure StringGrid1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
      var CanSelect: Boolean);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure restart();
    procedure compTurn();
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  gameBoard: array [1 .. 3, 1 .. 3] of char; // array for the game board.
  iScore: Integer;
  bTurn: Boolean = True; // O's go = false, X's go = true.

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  restart;
end;

procedure TForm1.compTurn;
begin
  // if (bTurn = false) then
  label1.Caption := 'Computer`s turn';

end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  restart;
end;

procedure TForm1.restart;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  // place ? in the cells
  StringGrid1.Enabled := True;

  for i := 1 to 3 do
    for j := 1 to 3 do
      StringGrid1.cells[i, j] := '?';
  label1.Caption := 'Player X`s turn';
end;

procedure TForm1.StringGrid1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var CanSelect: Boolean);
Var
  sX: string;
  pos: Integer;
begin

  sX := 'X';
  CanSelect := false;

  // Place a X or O in the cell depending on whose turn it is
  if (bTurn = True) then
    StringGrid1.cells[ACol, ARow] := sX // and gameBoard[ACol, ARow]

  else

    bTurn := false; // computer's turn to move
  compTurn; // make sure user can't add an X
  StringGrid1.Enabled := false;

end;

end.```
````

Comment: You don't need to use grave accents (`\``) as apostrophes (which is very wrong). To use a normal apostrophe in a Pascal string literal, type it two times: `''`.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Ah thanks. It's Delphi 10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was hoping at this part in the code it would add the 'X' to the
> gameboard array using the stringgrid.cell(ARow,ACol) for the position.
> I've now learnt that this cannot work as the array is a char type. Is
> there a way around this?

The problem you are facing here is that in your `StringGrid1SelectCell` event handler you defined your `sX` variable as string. So if you try to assign value of `sX` to your array of char Delphi won't let you since you cant store entire string into a sigle char.

To achieve desired functionality you should change your `sX` variable into a Char type instead. This will then allow you to write its value into your array.

Now you might be thinking that this would lead to problems since you also need to assign value of your `sX` variable to specific String Grid Cell since String Grid Cells are of String type. You won't.

You can always assign a single char to a string. This will change the length of that string to one an it will contain only the specific character you provided.

So in short:

- Assigning String to Char does not work
- Assigning Char to string does work

---

PS Also don't forget that if you need to execute multiple commands when if clause condition is met you need to enclose those commands with begin..end block.

So your code should look something like this (haven't tested it)

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var CanSelect: Boolean);
Var
  sX: Char; //Change type from String to Char
  pos: Integer;
begin

  sX := 'X';
  CanSelect := false;

  // Place a X or O in the cell depending on whose turn it is
  if (bTurn = True) then
  //Enclose multiple commands with begin..end block
  begin
    StringGrid1.cells[ACol, ARow] := sX // and gameBoard[ACol, ARow]
    GameBoard[ACol,ARow] := sX;
  else
    bTurn := false; // computer's turn to move
  compTurn; // make sure user can't add an X
  StringGrid1.Enabled := false;

end;
```